# Strategies for searching a list of numbers

Tags: python-3.x, list, iteration

Suppose I'm thinking of a secret number between 1 - 100.

You are asked to guess a number and I will respond "guess higher" or "guess lower" or "correct". The game continues until you guess correctly.

I'm interested in creating algorithms for searching for this secret number in a systematic way.

For Example,
Brute Force --- guess 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 100 until I'm correct

The reason I'm writing is to address another technique. I'm interested in guessing using a tree structure. For example, my first guess is 50. My second guess is either 25 or 75. My third guess is either 13 or 37 if I guessed 25 on the last round or my third guess is 63 or 87 if I guessed 75 on the last round. It's basically cutting the number line into smaller sections.

## This function chooses the next guess to make

```
def guessByDividing(prevGuess, feedback, floor, ceil):

    window = (ceil - floor)

    if prevGuess == 100:
        guess = int(prevGuess/2)
        return [guess, floor, ceil]

    if feedback == "guess higher":
        floor = prevGuess
        guess = int(prevGuess + (window / 2))
        return [guess, floor, ceil]

    elif feedback == "guess lower":
        ceil = prevGuess
        guess = int(prevGuess - (window / 2))
        return [guess, floor, ceil]
```

## This function checks the guess and provides clues.

```
def playDivideConquer():
    guessList = []
    gameOver = False
    feedback = "guess lower"
    guess = 100

    floor = 1
    ceil = 100

    while not gameOver:

        guess, floor, ceil = guessByDividing(guess, feedback, floor, ceil)
        guessList.append(guess)

        # Provide Clues
        if guess > secretNumber:
            print("Lower than " + str(guess) + "--- Number of guesses = " + str(len(guessList)))
            feedback = "guess lower"
        elif guess < secretNumber:
            print("Higher than " + str(guess) + "--- Number of guesses = " + str(len(guessList)))
            feedback = "guess higher"
        else:
            print("CORRECT --- The secret number is " + str(secretNumber))
            gameOver = True

        print(guessList)
```

It's not working correctly and I'm not sure how to fix the bug. Can anyone please help? I'm also interested in other strategies of finding the secret number quickly.

Thank you

Comment: If you have code that's not working, please explain **how** it's not working. It will save everyone some time.

Comment: The main issue I've found is that this code will replicate a guess multiple times. I'm looking to fix the algorithm so that it is more efficient and avoids repeating a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well I couldn't figure out what's wrong with your code yet. But from the question, I guess this is what you're looking for

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random

guessesTaken = 0

number = random.randint(1, 101)
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.')

while guessesTaken < 6:
    print('Take a guess.') 
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.') 

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm playing this game however I'm trying to get the computer to play against itself using a specific strategy. The strategy I'm trying to simulate is using a cut the range in half.

Comment: so you want the computer to play itself? I mean pick a number and guess it as well?